# Extension is showing effect/error after completly removing it magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I have installed `Simtech Searchanise` for searching function in staging and live site. After few week we came to know in both site , extension using same API key. So when i do any changes in live it reflect on staging and vice versa. So i completely(file/db_table) removed extension from staging site. After removing it showing error `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Searchanise_Helper_ApiSe' not found in app/Mage.php on line 547`.

To fix this i have removed `var/cache` , `var/session` and log tables from DB.
But it still showing error.

Anyone know why this issue is showing and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you go and check this extension does a direct override of this file

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml
```

In this file, this code has been written:

```
$searchaniseDisabled = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('advanced/modules_disable_output/Simtech_Searchanise');
            if (!$searchaniseDisabled) {
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                $showDefaultAutocomplete = !Mage::helper('searchanise/ApiSe')->checkSearchaniseResult(true, $store);
            }
```

Comment this out! And it should work!

Comment: if it works..please mark it as accept..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if there is anything left from it in /app/etc - simtech.xml or similar.

If there isn't then maybe try reinstalling the latest Magento Connect version ([here I think](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-autocomplete-search-suggest.html)) via your Magento Admin (System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager) and then once you have cleared cache, logged out then go back into Magento Connect Manager and uninstall it.

During the installation process using the above method if you get some errors then these should also give you a hint as to what files were left and are causing these issues from your previous install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed file name Simtech_Searchanise.xml from below location location ?

```
app->etc->modules->Simtech_Searchanise.xml
```

If not please remove that file also and removed cache again.

Comment: I have already removed Simtech_Searchanise.xml and removed the cache. but it still showing error.